# Cosmos DB speed issue

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm having a speed issue with Azure Cosmos where there seems to be a very slow step in my code. Please can anyone explain to me why the line FeedResponse response = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync(); is taking nearly 6 seconds to execute when the initial SQL call is in ms? I'm no expert in Cosmos and just trying it out. Cosmos container contains around 15,000 records and we're pulling back 1,1000. Partition key is "deviceID". Code and output below.

Example item from container

```
{
"id": "0",
"deviceID": "-6477270294724479467",
"MessageString": "N8P95FVW6B087IWV",
"_rid": "cmYXAPuQpaEBAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/cmYXAA==/colls/cmYXAPuQpaE=/docs/cmYXAPuQpaEBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"5e009882-0000-0700-0000-62d537c60000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1658140614
}
```

My code

```
public async Task<List<Message>?> ReadMultipleFromCosmosAsync(string partitionKey, string numrecords)
    {
        var tms = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Container container = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(this.databaseId).GetContainer(containerId);
        List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
        Console.WriteLine("Container accessed in {0}ms", tms.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        var pms = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var sqlQueryText = "SELECT TOP " + numrecords + " * FROM c WHERE c.deviceID = '" + partitionKey + "' ORDER BY c._ts DESC";
        QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
        using FeedIterator<Message> queryResultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Message>(queryDefinition);
        Console.WriteLine("SQL executed and iterator read through SQL query results in {0}ms", pms.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
                var rms = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                FeedResponse<Message> response = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Messages copied to FeedResponse in {0}ms", rms.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                var fms = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                foreach (var item in response)
                {
                    item.MessageDate = epoch2string(item._ts);
                    messages.Add(item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Individual messages added to List<T> in {0}ms", fms.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

Console output.....

---

Starting read

Creating Cosmos client

Cosmos client created in 777ms

Container accessed in 9ms

SQL executed and iterator read through SQL query results in 10ms

Messages copied to FeedResponse in 5599ms

Individual messages added to List in 6ms

Returnstring received by Program

1000 records retrieved from DB in 6450ms

---

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Have you initialized your CosmosClient before executing the query? Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943528/asp-net-core-3-application-slow-to-load-cosmos-db-query/.

Comment: It's being declared earlier in the code with this line but not initiated so will take a look at the link

this.cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey, new CosmosClientOptions() { ApplicationName = "HashGenerator" });

Thanks!

Comment: This is where you are instantiating it. Please see my answer from the previous comment regarding initialization.

Comment: Well that's certainly moved the slow step so we're now getting.
Cosmos client created in 5481ms
Container accessed in 0ms
SQL executed and iterator read through SQL query results in 2ms
Messages copied to FeedResponse in 1683ms
Individual messages added to List<T> in 12ms
Returnstring received by Program
1000 records retrieved from DB in 7211ms

If this were to be used in an ASP.Net web app could the Cosmos client be created and initialised when the app started and then persisted? There's no reason why it can't be reused is what I'm trying to get at?

Comment: `If this were to be used in an ASP.Net web app could the Cosmos client be created and initialised when the app started and then persisted?` - That's exactly how you would do it. Initialize a CosmosClient on app launch and then injected throughout the application via dependency injection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.net core 3 application slow to load cosmos db query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943528/asp-net-core-3-application-slow-to-load-cosmos-db-query)