# Cosmos DB Query Intermittent latency

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a singleton Cosmos DB Client running as a singleton with default options. I'm using a .NET 6.0 WebAPI project, running in an Azure app service with "Always-On" enabled.  The App Service and Cosmos Account are in the same region, UE2. The API queries a Cosmos container and returns the result.

I've noticed that the latency of the first query is always slow (4-6 seconds), subsequent queries are much faster (-100ms) but also sometimes have random high latency.  This is not a cold start scenario, the client has already been initialized by the DI pipeline. I'm also not being rate limited.

Here is my singleton client

```
    public CosmosDbService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var account = configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")["Account"];
        var key = configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")["Key"];
        var databaseName = configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")["DatabaseName"];
        var containerName = configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")["Container"];
        CosmosClient client = new (account, key);
        _myContainer = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
    }
```

Here is the meat of the query where a Linq query is being passed in:

```
 public class RetrieveCarRepository : IRetrieveCarRepository
{
    public async Task<List<CarModel>> RetrieveCars(IQueryable<CarModel> querydef)
    {
        var query = querydef.ToFeedIterator();

        List<CarModel> cars = new ();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

            foreach (var car in response)...do a thing
```

I've been through several Cosmos training videos and cosmos courses but still haven't been able to come to an idea of what is happening.

Comment: What is the P99 (99%) latency measured during 1hr? The first request being slower is expected as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-sdk-connection-modes#direct-mode. Have you checked the Diagnostics on the operations as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-slow-request?

Comment: Regarding the latency of 1st query, it is expected because you have only only instantiated the client object in the DI, it is not initialized. Client will get initialized on the 1st query. Please see my answer here regarding how you can initialize the client in the DI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943528/asp-net-core-3-application-slow-to-load-cosmos-db-query.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I actually started from your post :P.  I just re-read and I  misspoke. Regardless of when the initialization occurs, the client should maintain it's connections for the life of the client, so I shouldn't see latency later on right?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, I am going to deploy with an app insights logger to capture the diagnostics and come back.  Thanks for taking the time to respond. This isn't cold start, it's intermittant.

Comment: Keep in mind that different queries will have different latency too (your code is just an extension that executes any query). Also make sure to check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-local-query-plan-generation

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, big oof.  This app is running in 32-bit mode on the app service, which is a deployment error. If I read the documentation right, this may be a big part of the perceived latency.  I assume this means the client must go to the gateway first for the query plan.  Then the "latency" disappears if I repeat the query because there is some local caching?

Comment: HTTP latency can have jittery, and fluctuate, more than the TCP latency, so yes, this could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments.

For query performance using the .NET SDK please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-local-query-plan-generation

Query Plan generation can affect latency and can be avoided if:

1. The query is reworked to be on a single partition (instead of cross-partition).
2. The workload runs on Windows, compiled as x64 and with the Nuget DLLs co-located. Which in turn would leverage local query plan generation through the ServiceInterop.dll

On both cases the Query Plan request should be removed and latency improved.

As a general rule, latency should be investigated on the P99 across 1h to understand how it is impacted. A couple of higher latency requests can always happen.

Keep also in mind that query latency will vary based on the type of query, volume of data to transfer, and number of pages. You can capture the Diagnostics and use: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-slow-request